# Always show traceback() in interactive R

Tags: r

I'm developing a package for R. When I test it in the interactive R environment, I call `traceback()` very often.

Is there a way for me to configure interactive R to *always* show the `traceback()` message *automatically* when it encounters a runtime error? I don't want to have to type `traceback()` every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
options(error = traceback)
```

and you'll automatically get a traceback when an error occurs.  An even more useful choice is

```
options(error = utils::recover)
```

which prints something like a traceback but lets you examine the variables as they existed at the time of the error, or

```
options(error = utils::dump.frames)
```

which saves the variables so they can be examined later.

Any one of these commands could be put in your `.Rprofile` file and they would automatically apply in any session that used it.